# Not able to call http post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, observable

I am new to javascript world. httpService.post is never executed. How can I achieve this?

```
async createInboundRequest_1(payload: InboundRequestDto) {
  console.log("Request Dto ");
  console.log(payload);
  return this.fetchLookupReferenceData(payload).then(res => {
    console.log("Final Response ");
    console.log(res);
    this.httpService.post(this.api_url, res).pipe(
      map(res_1 => res_1.data),
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: Is "Final Response" logged out?

Comment: why `async createInboundRequest_1` if you never `await` inside `createInboundRequest_1` ? also, `return this.fetchLookupReferenceData(payload).then` ... you do realise you'll always return a Promise that resolves to `undefined` because you don't return anything in the `.then`?

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues suggested to change the above code as given below and it worked but I am still not sure why this works.

```js
 async createInboundRequest_1(payload: InboundRequestDto) {
    const enrichedRequest = await this.fetchLookupReferenceData(payload);
    const res = this.httpService.post(this.api_url, enrichedRequest).subscribe(res_1 => {
      return res_1.data;
    })
  }
```

Comment: The request happens when you subscribe. A implementation could look like 
createInboundRequest_1(payload).subscribe((response) => .....
Between post and subscribe you can pipe your response to manipulate it (filter, map, etc..).